# How to use data toggle collapse in Reactjs with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-router

I am using pure Bootstrap with Reactjs and I have build a navBar using Bootstrap component but the problem I am facing is with data toggle collapse it is not working.

When I shrink my display view size then the hamburger icon becomes visible but when I click on it then nothing happens. While it works perfect with pure HTML and JS but not working with reactjs.

Here is index.js file

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/navBar/navBar';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <NavBar />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is NavBar.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div className="navbar-nav">
              <a className="nav-item nav-link active" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Features</a>
              <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Pricing</a>
              <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

This is complete code I have used for navBar.

Comment: The reason is, that resizing window and appearance of the menu button is CSS thing. But the drop-down functionality is a JS thing  (Bootstrap JS library). Since React is also JS thing, these two things "clash". My input would be to NOT rely on Bootstrap in this matter and create your own pure React functionality... it's just a click of a button

Comment: include [bootstrap.min.js and jquery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) to make it work..

Comment: Don't include bootstrap.min.js and jquery, use react component, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Comment: @LudovitMydla okay but how to create pure react functionality?

Comment: @Ayushya I don't want to use any libraries isn't there any other way to do same without any libraries?

Comment: @NehaSharma well... check out Davo's answer

Comment: @ArupRakshit in index.html?

Comment: @LudovitMydla I am very new to react can you please tell how to insert my navBar code into this navBar? that Davo's had shown me.  Please! :-p

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bootstrap menu toggle is a JS functionality. It's not a good idea to mix the JS part of Bootstrap with ReactJS, since both libraries manipulate the DOM and it can lead to bigger problems.

I suggest implementing the small functionality you need. Most of the menu toggle is just a class toggle thing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Menu extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menu: false
    };
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
  }

  toggleMenu(){
    this.setState({ menu: !this.state.menu })
  }

  render() {

  const show = (this.state.menu) ? "show" : "" ;

  return (

    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" onClick={ this.toggleMenu }>
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div className={"collapse navbar-collapse " + show}>
        <div className="navbar-nav">
          <a className="nav-item nav-link active" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Features</a>
          <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Pricing</a>
          <a className="nav-item nav-link" href="/">logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an animation/transition associated with the bootstrap collapse, which is lost with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

There is an equivalent library called "react-bootstrap" that you can use to style your components the same way as you would use bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io. This way you can follow react and bootstrap best practices without making unnecessary manipulations to do DOM which can sometimes bring unwanted side effects.

Comment: but what if the button is in different component?

Answer (score 2):

**Best Solution is the simplest :**

```
<div style={show?{display:"block"}:{display:'none'}} className={"collapse navbar-collapse"}>........</div>
```

where show is a :   const [show, setShow]=React.useState(false);

and on the button:  onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}