# Menubar toggle in mobile view, not collapsing

Tags: html, reactjs

I am facing this issue where I use the bootstrap navigation bar, and that `nav` bar is not collapsing itself when the component changes. Have a look [here](https://www.useloom.com/share/705c86cff7844e71ab6a3f9b1988ffb7)

Here is the content of my file `Menubar.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header id="header">
          <nav className="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="navbar-toggle"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span className="icon-bar" />
                  <span className="icon-bar" />
                  <span className="icon-bar" />
                </button>

                <a href="#">
                  <img
                    src="images/dew_vantures.png"
                    alt="DEW"
                    className="img-responsive"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>

              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li>
                    <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to={"/About"}>About</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to={"/Contact"}>Contact Us</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

But when I use this approach in pure HTML5 or PHP it works fine,

[Here](https://www.useloom.com/share/dab865f0d38d44d1a1d7816eba3436b4) is a working example.

I have used the following example but it is not working for me:

> [How to use data toggle collapse in Reactjs with Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248179/how-to-use-data-toggle-collapse-in-reactjs-with-bootstrap)